# UITextField editingChange Control Event not works

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have some textfields and I want to do when I change textfield1 text set text to other textfields. My code below. But it not works. How can I solve this?

```
- (IBAction)TCKimlikTextChange:(id)sender {

[TCKimlikText addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

-(void)yourMethod: (UITextField*)tf_{

if (tf_) {
    if (TCKimlikText.text == @"1") {
        AdinizText.text = @"Hacer";
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very abstract. `yourMethod`, `tf_` `TCKimlikTextChange` are all expressions that are not very human readable. You should work on your variable names.

I suppose your first method is a button handler. It just assigned a target and action to the text field, but does not call any method. You do not need that action if you use the delegate protocol.

To solve your problem: implement the `UITextField` delegate methods. Make sure you set the delegate (probably `self`) for your text fields. Your view controller must mention the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in its `.h` file. Thus, in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`:

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
   displayLabel.text = @"Hacer";
}
```

Notice that you need `isEqualToString:` to compare strings, a simple `==` won't do.

Comment: what is textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString::

Comment: Also I allready add delegate and <UITextFieldDelegate>.And then I try your "isEqualToString"  way but it not works, too.

Comment: Did you implement `textField:shouldChangeCharacters...`? It should pop up in your `.m` file if you start typing `-text`.

Answer (score 0):

If u are want to change on the click of the return button use the delegate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == field1)
        [field2 setText:field1.text];

    [field1 resignFirstResponder];
    return  YES;

}
```

or u can use other delegates too like: 
– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:

Comment: I try also – textFieldDidBeginEditing: but it not worked, too